# Is there a tool for parsing feeds in Django

Tags: python, django, feed, atom-feed

I did some googling and didn't find anything complete for my problem, but it is so generic, there has to be something.

I need feed parsing tool for my Django app (i want to fetch atom feed from somewhere and store its contents). I just found some feedparser.py references but the actual site is a long gone.

Could you provide some pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

feedparser is still pretty much the canonical solution for this in Python. It's very far from gone: see [the documentation here](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) and the [actual project page here](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser)

Comment: If you like to use django, maybe you look at https://github.com/operasoftware/django-feeds