# Pull Wordpress feed into Django template

Tags: django, wordpress

What I'd like to do is extract the headline and URL out of the feed data from my wordpress blog, and display it as a link within my Django template.

I found [this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Categories_and_Tags)

But it doesn't prove useful in Django. (I'm a n00b). So I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how I might grab the feeb and place it into a Django application?

```
<a href="link-to-feed">Title of blog post</a>
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to parse your wordpress feed in your Django View, then send that rendered data to your template.

[Good Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761198/is-there-a-tool-for-parsing-feeds-in-django)
also feedparser specs: http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/

Do some research in parsing XML with Python in your Django view

```
1. Hit the Wordpress Feed URL in view.py
2. Parse the resulting XML nodes (or feedparser I think)
3. Extract needed data
4. Send data to your django template from the view
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I found this to be really helpful too: 
http://geekscrap.com/2010/02/integrate-wordpress-and-django/

I'm using option 2, the xmlrpc. here's the github page for examples

https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/blob/master/docs/examples/posts.rst

this pulls right from the rss feed, just as the other answer. I dont know how performant this solution is vs the other one though, sorry.

Comment: no problem! we're using it right now to pull our wordpress.com hosted blog into our regular website for tighter control over the presentation of it all. Working great so far. good luck!